# TFileOpenDialog FileTypes : how to change at runtime

Tags: delphi, filter, openfiledialog

In a TFileOpenDialog I set the FileTypes property to a custom list of files populated by selected files from the current folder.

```
dlg := TFileOpenDialog.Create( self );
Filter := TStringList.Create();
// ... 
// Filter contains the selected files
  if Filter.Count>0 then
    begin
      msg := '';
      for i := 0 to Filter.Count-1 do
          msg := msg + Filter[i] + ';';
      dlg.FileTypes.Clear;
      dlg.FileTypes.Add.DisplayName := '';
      dlg.FileTypes.Add.FileMask := msg;
    end;
```

It works as desired.

I handle the OnFolderChange event in that I create a new file selection from the newly selected folder. I set the FileTypes property to this new list.
But I observe that the FileTypes property remains unchanged. As a result no files are found.

Am I right to assume that the FileTypes property cannot be changed for the current TFileOpenDialog?

Comment: This line `dlg.FileTypes.Add.DisplayName := '';` adds one file type and this line `dlg.FileTypes.Add.FileMask := msg;` adds another one. Try use `with` operator: `with dlg.FileTypes.Add do begin DisplayName := ''; FileMask := msg; end;`

Comment: Thank you - this prevents a first empty filter item. But the problem of not updating FileTypes remains.

Comment: Wait let me get this straight. You are using FileTypes filter to only show specific files from specific folder? That is not what FileTypes filter is intented to be used for. FileTyoes filter is intended for TOpenDialog to only show files of specific type (for instance only images) in order to alow user to find specific file more easily and prevent him in trying to open unsuported file type.

Comment: My intention is to filter "File_A_*.csv" from a folder containing "File_A_*.csv", "File_B_*.csv" and "File_C_*.csv" before the user selects from the filtered files. The FilterType option is the only way I found so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This control is a wrapper around the common item dialog. The documentation for [`IFileDialog::SetFileTypes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775980.aspx) says:

> This method must be called before the dialog is shown and can only be called once for each dialog instance. File types cannot be modified once the Common Item dialog box is displayed.

So you cannot modify the file types after the dialog has been shown.

FWIW, each time you call `FileTypes.Add` you are adding a new file type. You need to call `FileTypes.Add` once per file type.

Comment: I call 'FileTypes.Add' only once and add a fairly log string composed of the selected files separated by ';'. This FileType item does not look good but filters as desired. - Now it's clear to me why the FileTypes cannot be modified, thank you.